# I've a problem about printing file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, printing

I want to print some numbers from a file I've found them through `line.startswith()` but I want to sum them and they're strings and not float so i cant add them. How can I convert them in floats.

Here is my code:

```py
    file='mbox.txt'
    handle=open(file)
    count=0
    for line in handle:
        if line.startswith('X-DSPAM-Confidence:'):
            count=count+1
            numeri(line[20:])
            num='%g'%float(numeri.strip(' \n '))
            n=sum(num)
    print('Le stringhe che iniziano con "X-DSPAM-Confidence:" sono' ,count)
    print(n)
```

Sorry for the english and coding errors but i'm pretty new in this

Comment: With `num='%g'%float(numeri.strip(' \n '))` you cast it back to a string. Just use `num = float(numeri.strip())`.

Answer (score 0):

Hare is the code modified and sum the values obtained from the file.

```py
def main():
    file='mbox.txt'
    handle=open(file)
    count=0
    numeri=''
    my_sum = 0;
    count =0
    for line in handle:
        if line.startswith('X-DSPAM-Confidence:'):
            count=count+1
            numeri = line[20:]
            num='%g'%float(numeri.strip(' \n '))
            print float(num)
            my_sum = my_sum + float(num)

    print('Le stringhe che iniziano con "X-DSPAM-Confidence:" sono' ,count)
    print my_sum 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I assumed that the file contains things like the following (as you did not post its content):

```
X-DSPAM-Confidence: 1
X-DSPAM-Confidence: 2
X-DSPAM-Confidence: 3
X-DSPAM-Confidence: 4 
X-DSPAM-Confidence: 5
```

The output would be the following:

```
1.0
2.0
3.0
4.0
5.0
('Le stringhe che iniziano con "X-DSPAM-Confidence:" sono' ,5)
15.0
```

The last number is the sum of all the numbers

Comment: I had numbers like this in file: 0.8765   0.7644 so i had to change this in float.

Comment: Could you explain why you first convert `numeri` to a float with `float(numeri.strip(' \n '))` then to a string with `num='%g'%float(numeri.strip(' \n '))` and then back to a float again in `sum = sum + float(num)`? I don't see a reason for that but I might be overlooking something. And overwriting the builtin [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) isn't the best of ideas.